# Построение запроса на сопадения в БД

Tags: laravel

Имеется следующий запрос в БД.

```
 $data = Workers::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] . '%',
            'OR', 'position', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] . '%',
            'OR', 'salary', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] . '%',
            'OR', 'work_permit', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] .'%')
            ->get();
```

При в воде числа в поисковую строку третье и четвертое условие не срабатывает и выборка оказывается пустой. Если убрать первое и второе условие начинает срабатывать третье. Убираем третье срабатывает четвертое. Причина такого поведения мне не ясна.

Answer (score 0):

Очередной раз правило если, что то не работает читай инструкцию оказалось верным.

```
  $data = Workers::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] . '%')
            ->orWhere('position', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] . '%')
            ->orWhere('salary', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] . '%')
            ->orWhere('work_permit', 'LIKE', '%' . $orderData['search'] . '%')
            ->get();
```